# Docker volumes : specifying permissions using mount options

Tags: docker, mount, docker-volume

I'm trying to use a named volume mounted in a Docker container, but get a `Permission denied` error when trying to create a file in the mounted folder. So I'm trying to use `mount` options when creating my volume, but that does not work as I want.

### Introduction

I'm totally aware that when mounting a volume (created by `docker volume create my_named_volume`) with the option `-v my_named_volume:/home/user/test` or `--mount type=volume,source=my_named_volume,target=/home/user/test`), the folder inside the container (`/home/user/test` will be owned by `root` user, even if `/home/user` belongs to an user `user` created in my `Dockerfile`. If I run :

```
docker run --rm \
    --name test_named_volume \
    --mount type=volume,source=my_named_volume,target=/home/user/test \
    test_named_volume \
    su user -c "touch /home/user/test/a"
```

Then I get :

```
touch: cannot touch '/home/user/test/a': Permission denied
```

I'm understanding that. That's why I'm trying to use `mount` options when creating my volume.

### `mount` options

I'm specifying an `uid` when creating my volume, in order to make my user `user` able to create a file in that volume :

```
docker volume create my_named_volume \
    --opt o=uid=1000
```

`1000` is the `uid` of the user `user` created in my `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM    debian:jessie

ENV     HOME /home/user

RUN     useradd \
            --create-home \
            --home-dir $HOME \
            --uid 1000 \
            user \
 &&     chown -R user:user $HOME

WORKDIR $HOME
```

But when running my container (with the same command `docker run` defined above), I'm getting an error (`missing device in volume options`) :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/my_named_volume/_data': missing device in volume options.
```

From [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options), I see that options `--device` and `--type` are missing from my volume creation :

```
docker volume create my_named_volume \
    --opt device=??? \
    --opt type=??? \
    --opt o=uid=1000
```

But I cannot see why I must give these options. `device` needs to be a block device, and from what I read, `type` should be something like `ext4`. But what I want is basically **just** set the `uid` option to my volume. It looks like creating a block device should work, but it seems too much configuration for a "simple" problem.

I have tried to use `tmpfs` for `device` and `type`, that works fine (file `/home/user/test/a` is created)... until my container is stopped (the data is not persisted, and that's logical because it's `tmpfs`). I want to persist that data written in the volume when the container exits.

What is the simplest way to specify permissions when mounting a named volume in a container? I don't want to modify my Dockerfile to use some magic (entrypoint that `chown` and then execute the command for example). It seems possible using `mount` options, I feel like I'm close to the solution, but maybe I'm in the wrong way.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564861/mount-named-volume-as-non-root-in-docker) can be of solution to you, can you please try?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what your issue is, but this worked for me:

```
docker run --name test_named_volume \
  --mount type=volume,source=test_vol,target=/home/user \
  --user user \
  test_named_volume touch /home/user/a
```

I think where you could have gone wrong is:

1. Your mount target is `/home/user/test` has not been created yet, since the `useradd` command in your Dockerfile only creates `$HOME` (`/home/user`). So docker creates the directory within the container with root permissions.
2. You were not using the `--user` flag in docker run to run the container as the specified user.

Comment: Unfortunately, I really need to mount the volume on a folder that does not exist yet in the container (`/home/user/test`). My use-case is a little bit more complicated than the provided example. Actually, the `test` folder is a config folder (`.config`), and the entrypoint is an executable run by `user` (`su user -c <executable>`), storing data in that `.config` folder. But basically it's the same problem I explained, I hope that gives a little more context about my issue.

Comment: In that case you can address this in two ways - create the folder beforehand  in the Dockerfile, or change permissions on the parent directory which you know will exist (/home/user/) in the Dockerfile and mount this directory instead.

Comment: As I said in the last paragraph, modifying the Dockerfile is not a suitable solution. Mounting the `/home/user` directory to **one** volume surely works, but potentially I could have multiple folders in that directory and want to mount different directories (`/home/user/test1`, `/home/user/test2`, ...) on different volumes. That's why I tried to use `mount` options instead of these solutions.

Comment: I came across the same problem and cannot find a solution. Setting a permission to a newly created mount point in docker config is like "1+1=2" in math. There a lot of people with this problem and I have no idea why this is not supported since version 1.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this issue.  And contrary to popular belief the mount did NOT pickup the permissions of the host mounted directory, it reset them.

When I did this, the permissions were changed to 777 inside the container...

```
volumes:
    - ./astro-nginx-php7/logs:/home/webowner/zos/log:rw
```

The :rw made all the difference for me.  My image was nginx:latest.
Docker compose version 3.3

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Maybe you're running docker-for-mac which might have different volume permissions behavior.

Comment: This worked for me as well, also on Docker for Mac.