# Mount volumes as non root user in docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to mount a volume in the docker container as a non root user. I am using the following (k8s.yaml) -

```
volumeMounts:
        - name: volume-to-be-mounted
          mountPath: /location
volumes:
        - name:  volume-to-be-mounted
          hostPath:
            path: path
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

This volume is mounted as root inside the container. But I want to mount it as non-root. Is there any way of doing this? I can also use the https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/  but I want to mount the same volume on other container (in the same pod) as well.

Some of the solutions that come to mind but don't suit my use case -

1. change the permissions of the directory in entrypoint (not viable because entrypoint will be run as a non root user.)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39576814/9081810 I am using k8s.yaml to specify my requirements. I don't know how this solution will fit in.

Possible solutions that can work but I don't know how to do it -

1. set permissions to 777 while mounting the volume.

Comment: I'd expect the ConfigMap contents to be read-only (though can't find a statement to this effect in the documentation).  Just so long as the active user can read the files there, does it actually matter what user owns them?

Comment: I want to write in that specific location. Will remove the config map from the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using kubernetes you can use a [security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) and set the `fsGroup` value.

Example from the docs

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    fsGroup: 2000
  volumes:
  - name: sec-ctx-vol
    emptyDir: {}
  containers:
  - name: sec-ctx-demo
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: sec-ctx-vol
      mountPath: /data/demo
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

If you're just using docker ... well there's been an [open issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259) since 2013

Answer (score 2):

you can consider running init container as a root user. have init container and main container share the same volume. from init container update the ownership of the volume

Comment: Changing the ownership from init container will be only reflected in the init container and not the application container. I tried - chown -R user:user folder

Comment: are you sure the volume is shared between the two containers?

Answer (score 1):

You want to mount the same volume on other container (in the same pod) as well.
I don't think you can do this.
The definition of pod is:`A pod (as in a pod of whales or pea pod) is a group of one or more containers (such as Docker containers), with shared storage/network, and a specification for how to run the containers.`
more detail: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/