# How to write to docker volume inside shiny app?

Tags: r, docker, shiny, docker-volume

Here is the project directory:

```
❯ tree ../write-to-volume-from-shiny
../write-to-volume-from-shiny
├── app.R
├── Dockerfile
└── shiny-server.conf
```

---

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/shiny:4.3.1
RUN rm /srv/shiny-server/index.html /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY app.R /srv/shiny-server
COPY shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/
RUN chmod -R 755 /srv/shiny-server/
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server"]
```

---

The app file:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("touch", "Touch file"),
  textOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$touch, {
    if (fs::dir_exists("/data")) {
      fs::file_touch("/data/touch-test")
      // Error here because of shiny user
      // trying to write to root owned /data
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Shiny server conf:

```
run_as shiny;

server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

---

---

### Set up the volume

```
docker volume create --name write-test
```

---

### Run the app

```
docker buildx build . -t write
docker run --mount source=write-test,target=/data -p 80:80 write
```

---

### Use the app

Go to [127.0.0.1:80](http://127.0.0.1:80)

click on button produces an error which I guess happens because `shiny` user is trying to write to `root` owned `/data`

What is the workaround here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39576814/6537892) (took me hours to find it), I have managed to modify `Dockerfile` and make it work:

The line `RUN mkdir /data && chown shiny:shiny /data` is the key:

```
FROM rocker/shiny:4.3.1
RUN rm /srv/shiny-server/index.html /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY app.R /srv/shiny-server
COPY shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/
RUN chmod -R 755 /srv/shiny-server/
RUN mkdir /data && chown shiny:shiny /data
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server"]
```